# How to switch to another DNS server permanently

Tags: linux, networking, dns, linux-mint

Sometimes, when I am in some problematic network, I get DNS errors like this `fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/user/repo/': Could not resolve host: github.com` I add to the `/etc/resolv.conf` one of this lines and it fix the problem:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

But when I reboot this lines are erased too. How can I do it permanently?

I'm using Linux Mint 17.2

Comment: From AskUbuntu: [The “resolv.conf” file becomes empty after each restart](http://askubuntu.com/questions/260538/the-resolv-conf-file-becomes-empty-after-each-restart) and [How do I add a DNS server via resolv.conf?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/130452/how-do-i-add-a-dns-server-via-resolv-conf)

Comment: `dhclient` is the program that performs DHCP to get an IP when connecting to a new network.  It overwrites this file upon connecting with info from the DHCP server that answered.  You can tell it to ignore what the network said and use what you want.  Check here and use the `supersede` option.  http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/dhclient-etcresolvconf-hooks/

Comment: Did you edit the connection in the GUI, add those dns servers? Basically click on network icon -> Edit

Comment: @Xen2050 I edited the file by hand :P

Comment: @LawrenceC thank you too.
I think this ask can be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using stock Mint, then you are using Network Manager for your wired / wireless connections.  It you go into Wired or Wireless settings from the status bar and Edit, you should have a dialog like this (theme / colors are probably different for you):

[image]

Just slide the DNS Automatic setting to Off, and enter specific DNS server IP addresses to use.  This will override what is coming from the DHCP server and essentially be permanent.  You can then, of course, go back in here and delete the IPs and change back to automatic to use the DNS servers supplied by a local DHCP server.